# Rails 5 Memory Bloat by Rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, memory-management

After spending the last few months learning rails and launching my first web application I have found out that I am experiencing Memory Bloat (see Scout screenshots for more info)!

I have tried looking through Scout documents and StackOverflow but at the moment nothing has worked.

This is what I know:

1. Locally, my rendering speeds seem to be working fine. As soon as I click, bam everything shows up quickly (at most 1 second).
2. On my Heroku server, I am experiencing intense slowing down (roughly 12 seconds)!
3. After I render the page once, then the consecutive renderings are much quicker (less than 1 second). My guess is that there is some form of caching that is helping me out.

Thank you in advanced!

#### orders/index.html.erb

Here is were Scout has said the memory bloat occurs.

```
<table class="alt">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="2u">Frequency</th>
                <th class="3u">Letters</th>
                <th class="4u">Next Reminder</th>
                <th class="1u">Active</th>
                <th class="2u">View Order</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
                <!-- Renders orders/_order.html.erb -->
                <%#= render @orders %>
                <% @orders.each do |order| %>
                  <%= render order %>
                <% end %>
              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2"></td>
                  <td colspan="3"><%= will_paginate(@orders) %></td>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
          </table>
```

#### Order partial (_order.html.erb)

```
<tr id="order-<%= order.id %>">
    <td><%= order.freq %></td>
    <td><%= pluralize(order.microposts.length, "post") %></td>
    <td><%= show_time(order.reminder) %></td>
    <td><%= human_boolean(order.continue) %></td>
    <td>
        <%= link_to "View", order_microposts_path(order) %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

#### Order controller

```
  def index
    # @user from application controller
    # Get orders including microposts (for size)
    @orders = Order.includes(:microposts).where(user_id: params[:user_id])
                              .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end
```

#### Local logs Rendering

```
Started GET "/users/1/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-18 16:41:45 -0800
Processing by OrdersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering orders/index.html.erb within layouts/application
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  Order Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."user_id" = ? ORDER BY "orders"."created_at" DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 5], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Micropost Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."order_id" IN (117, 116, 115, 114, 113) ORDER BY "microposts"."created_at" DESC
  Rendered orders/_order.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered orders/_order.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered orders/_order.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered orders/_order.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered orders/_order.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered orders/index.html.erb within layouts/application (29.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_bootstrap_template.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_body-tag.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_header-tag.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_rails-dev.html.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 68ms (Views: 62.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

#### Scout Rendering Usage

[image: Scout Rendering]

#### Scout Memory Bloat

[image: Scout Memory Bloat]

Comment: How much data does this request return? Is it a multi-MB HTML response? One request won't give you any useful data. You have to hit this thing hundreds of times to see if that memory allocation accumulates, or if it's simply a lot of garbage that can get recycled.

Comment: @tadman Let me know if I answered your questions. Basically, I have an Order model and I am simply am trying to render the contents of the Order to the user (note some of the Orders contain Microposts another Model). The results from scouts were from me going online and clicking view orders. In production it takes around 13 seconds to render the Orders the first time, after the first time it takes 1 second or less.

Comment: All my Rails experience is old (v3), but this looks like you're not precompiling assets and the first hit is doing the compilation.

Comment: @Gene Would this make sense: "heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile"

Whenever I try "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile" I can get an aws key error.

Answer (score 0):

You're rendering a partial in a loop, which isn't very efficient, the recommended method would be to render the partial once, and pass the object in as a collection:

```
= render partial: 'orders/order', collection: @orders
```

Or the shorthand that you have commented out should work as well:

```
= render @orders
```

Comment: Umm, okay let me try it. I actually had it like that before and had the same problem. (crossing my fingers)

Comment: Follow up: I tried <%= render partial: 'orders/order', collection: @orders %> but it didn't work.

Comment: You may just need to say `render partial: 'order'` instead of 'orders/order', the collection method is really finicky about everything being named properly.

Comment: Sadly no luck. Is there any other logs or info you recommend me to look at to troubleshoot?

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, it looks like that should work. But i do strongly feel like that is where your performance issue lies, I would take a minute to look over section 3.4.5 here, and try to get that working: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Yeah, it seems that collections are supposed to make things faster, however, it isn't doing it in my case. Do you think this is a rails issue more than a Heroku issue? (I just want to make sure I am chasing the right bug)

Comment: I'm stumped honestly, with your eager loading and partial collection rendering it should be pretty fast. You could try looking into optimizing the query if there are a ton of records, I'm not sure where else the bottleneck could be. https://blog.codeship.com/speed-up-activerecord/

Comment: Just to make sure, you also agree my Orders Controller is correctish? (Thanks for the help mate!)